# Kotlin + SimpleXMLElement + Map sublist element

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, simple-framework

I'm developing an Android App with Kotlin. I need to consume an API that returns an XML to a request.

For example the returned XML is:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <ListaEmpresasResponse xmlns="http://example.com/">
         <ListaEmpresasResult>
            <IdEstado>001</IdEstado>
            <Mensaje/>
            <Empresas>
               <Empresa>
                  <IdEmpresas>1</IdEmpresas>
                  <Nombre>Test 1</Nombre>
               </Empresa>
               <Empresa>
                  <IdEmpresas>2</IdEmpresas>
                  <Nombre>Test2</Nombre>
               </Empresa>
               <Empresa>
                  <IdEmpresas>4</IdEmpresas>
                  <Nombre>Test 3</Nombre>
               </Empresa>
               <Empresa>
                  <IdEmpresas>5</IdEmpresas>
                  <Nombre>Test 4</Nombre>
               </Empresa>
            </Empresas>
         </ListaEmpresasResult>
      </ListaEmpresasResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I'm able to parse the IdEstado and Mensaje fields but i need to create a list with the elements called "Empresa".

I have file called mapper.kt

```
interface Mapper<in R, out T> {

    fun transform(input: R): T
    fun transformList(inputList: List<R>): List<T>

}
```

I have a file called DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityMapper.kt

```
import com.example.smt.data.model.datostrabajo.DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntity
import com.example.smt.data.model.datostrabajo.DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityEmpresa
import com.example.smt.data.model.datostrabajo.DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEnvelope
import com.example.smt.data.model.datostrabajo.Empresa
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_datostrabajo.view.*

class DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityMapper: Mapper<DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEnvelope, DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntity> {

    override fun transform(input: DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEnvelope): DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntity {
        return DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntity(
            input.body!!.listaEmpresasResponse!!.listaEmpresasResult!!.resultCode,
            input.body!!.listaEmpresasResponse!!.listaEmpresasResult!!.message,
            null<-- This is where i should parse the sublist where i'm not able to.
        )
    }




    override fun transformList(inputList: List<DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEnvelope>): List<DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntity> {
        return inputList.map { transform(it) }
    }

}

class DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityMapperEmpresa: Mapper<Empresa, DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityEmpresa>{
    override fun transform(input: Empresa): DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityEmpresa {
        return DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityEmpresa(
            input.idEmpresas,
            input.nombre
        )
    }

    override fun transformList(inputList: List<Empresa>): List<DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityEmpresa> {
        return inputList.map { transform(it) }
    }
}
```

My response file DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresa.kit where i have the structure defined is:

```
import org.simpleframework.xml.Element
import org.simpleframework.xml.Namespace
import org.simpleframework.xml.NamespaceList
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList



@Root(name = "soap:Envelope")
@NamespaceList(
    Namespace(prefix = "soap", reference = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"),
    Namespace(prefix = "xsi", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
    Namespace(prefix = "xsd", reference = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
)
class DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEnvelope {
    @field:Element(name = "Body", required = false)
    var body: DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaBody? = null
}

@Root(name = "soap:Body", strict = false)
class DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaBody {
    @field:Element(name = "ListaEmpresasResponse", required = false)
    var listaEmpresasResponse: ListaEmpresasResponse? = null
}

@Root(name = "ListaEmpresasResponse", strict = false)
class ListaEmpresasResponse {
    @field:Element(name = "ListaEmpresasResult", required = false)
    var listaEmpresasResult: ListaEmpresasResult? = null
}

@Root(name = "ListaEmpresasResult", strict = false)
class ListaEmpresasResult {
    @field:Element(name = "IdEstado", required = false)
    var resultCode: String? = null

    @field:Element(name = "Mensaje", required = false)
    var message: String? = null

    @field:ElementList(name = "Empresas", required = false)
    var empresas: List<Empresa>? = null

}

@Root(name = "Empresa", strict = false)
class Empresa {
    @field:Element(name = "IdEmpresas", required = false)
    var idEmpresas: Int? = null

    @field:Element(name = "Nombre", required = false)
    var nombre: String? = null
}
```

And at last this is my entity file DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntity.kt:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.android.parcel.Parcelize

@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
@Parcelize
data class DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityEmpresa(
    val idEmpresas: Int?,
    val nombre: String?
) : Parcelable

@SuppressLint("ParcelCreator")
@Parcelize
data class DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntity(
    val resultCode: String?,
    val message: String?,
    val empresas: List<DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityEmpresa?>
) : Parcelable
```

At the end what i expect is to have an attribut in my entity with the list List my problem is that i tried to parse it but not able. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you can afford to use beautifulsoup for java/kotlin, it's a lot easier. I used it to parse the xml files from openstreetmaps in a very simple way, like python. If you are interested, I will post an answer with an example.

Comment: Hi @Nosvan i accept any help, even is not maeby the better solution at this moment but if i don't find any other solution i would think about using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i found the solution:

```
input.body!!.listaEmpresasResponse!!.listaEmpresasResult!!.empresas!!.map { it  }.map{ DatosTrabajoResponseEmpresaEntityEmpresa(it.idEmpresas, it.nombre) }
```

Comment: You should avoid using "!!" when it isn't absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you can afford to use beautifulsoup for java/kotlin, it's a lot easier. I used it to parse the xml files from openstreetmaps in a very simple way, like python. The name of the library is Jsoup.

In this link (https://jsoup.org/download) you can see how to add it by graddle, maven and the jar to download. The usage is pretty straight-forward. This is an example from this (http://www.gitshah.com/2018/02/using-jsoup-with-kotlin-to-parse-html.html) tutorial:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup
import org.junit.Test

class JsoupTest {

    @Test
    fun shouldParseHTML() {
        //1. Fetching the HTML from a given URL
        Jsoup.connect("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=this+is+a+test").get().run {
            //2. Parses and scrapes the HTML response
            select("div.rc").forEachIndexed { index, element ->
                val titleAnchor = element.select("h3 a")
                val title = titleAnchor.text()
                val url = titleAnchor.attr("href")
                //3. Dumping Search Index, Title and URL on the stdout.
                println("$index. $title ($url)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to state that you want to use a xml parser, like it's said here (http://tonyjunkes.com/blog/parsing-xml-with-jsoup-in-cfml/).

```
doc = Jsoup.parse(rawXML, "", Parser.xmlParser());
```

You can validate the xml with a validator and a scheme using javafx like here (https://turreta.com/2018/06/24/kotlin-validate-xml-against-xsds/).

```
val factory: SchemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")

val schemaLocation = File("/somewhere/xsd/myschema.xsd")
val schema = factory.newSchema(schemaLocation)
val validator = schema.newValidator()
val source = StreamSource("/somewhere/test-data/myxml-test.xml")

println("Validation Starts now!")

val start = System.currentTimeMillis()
try {
    validator.validate(source)
    println(" XML is valid.")
} catch (ex: SAXException) {
    println(" XML not valid because " + ex.message)
}

println("Validation complete!")

println("Time (ms): " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
```

You can also use Jackson as stated here and as a bonus you get everything in dataclasses (https://medium.com/@foxjstephen/how-to-actually-parse-xml-in-java-kotlin-221a9309e6e8). This is the jackson's repository: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson.